# recurrence relation associated Legendre functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

I need a little help to find the recurrence relation
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}P_l^m(x) = \frac{1}{2l+1} (P_{l-1}^{m+1}-p_{l+1}^{m+1})$$
Using the identity
$$(2l+1)P_l(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(P_{l+1}(x)-P_{l-1}(x))$$

I have $$P_l^m(x) = (-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dx}P_l(x)$$

I guess I have to isolate $P_l(x)$, but I'm not sure how to manipulate this expression to plug it in the identity. I'm really stuck, any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

For the Legendre polynomials, the difference
$$
P_{l + 1}(x) - P_{l - 1}(x)
$$
satisfies the identity
$$
(2 l + 1) P_l(x) = {d \over dx}\left( P_{l + 1}(x) - P_{l - 1}(x) \right) \tag{1}
$$

If we act on the identity (1) with
$$
(-1)^m (1 - x^2)^{(m + 1)/2} d^m,
$$
the result follows.

Comment: What does act means? I mean If I try to multiply both side by $$(-1)^m (1 - x^2)^{(m + 1)/2} d^m,$$
On the left hand side I got something like $$(-1)^m (1 - x^2)^{(m + 1)/2} d^m (2l+1)P_l(x)$$ I'm not sure what I suppose to do with the $$d^m$$

Comment: 'd' is the operator ${d \over dx}$

Comment: I meant, do we assume there is a dx. Since $$P_l^m(x) = (-1)^m(1-x^2)^{m/2}\frac{d^m}{dx}P_l(x)$$

Comment: You substitute $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}$ in place of $d^m$ which is just shorthand for the $m$-th order derivative